# Passthrough does not return decimal values anymore

Tags: vba, t-sql, ms-access, pass-through

Hope I don't ask an already existing question. Didn't find a solution on the internet after a couple of hours of search.
I think this issue is pretty new, maybe caused by a recent update.

In my MS Access VBA code, I am using passthrough queries to get results from SPs on my MS SQL Server.
For a few weeks now, I do not receive decimal values as results anymore, the values are just *null* in this case.

Here is a very easy code example:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT 'abcde' AS string, '2020-07-01' AS date, 123.45 AS decimal, 3 as int"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = [here is my connectiong string]
qdf.SQL = strSQL
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

When working with that result, e.g. by copying that into an Excel file, the string; date, and integer value are written as required. Only the decimal value is a *null* instead.

Hope I didn't miss any essential information here. If you have any questions, just let me know.

Thanks for the help in advance!

BR,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears that your code was working and now isn't, it may be that you have encountered a recent bug in Microsoft Access: [Access VBA/DAO code may crash or report incorrect data for Decimal columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-vba-dao-code-may-crash-or-report-incorrect-data-for-decimal-columns-9311f0ab-ac34-40b4-abd7-2aaa01e07fc7?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) which has now apparently been fixed.

Regards,

Comment: Updating Access fixed it! Seems like I was just too impatient. Thanks @all!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to cast/type your values.  You are actually creating calculated fields.

Surrounding your date strings with hashes indicates that the values are dates:

> ```
> #2020-07-01#
> ```

Use the appriate  C function to cast all numeric values:

> ```
> Cdbl(123.45)
> CInt(3)
> ```